# Corrupt Project in Visual Studio - Key Already Added

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution that refuses to open

I get the useless error of Key Has Already Been Added

I looked at the solution and the project name is not duplicated, nor are the GUIDs

Even more strange and concerning is that I get the same error if I open the project on its own

I have tried deleting the .vs folder and that doesn't make any difference

The fact that the project doesnt load on its own is concerning and making me think this is getting cached somewhere else

I am using Visual Studio 2017

Has anyone ever come across this?

I recreated the 2 class libraries which took me a while and it still doesnt work

As soon as I restart VS I get the error again

Paul

Comment: Can you open a brand new project?

Comment: Yep that’s fine but I need this solution to open in full there are 2 which just won’t load no matter what!

Comment: Have you read through any of these questions to see if they have a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvisual-studio%5D+key+Has+Already+Been+Added

Comment: yep hardly any of them are relevant to me, as they ofen refer to nuget, etc.  I did try to delete the vs folder which was in one of the hints but that didnt work

Comment: This is a seriously annoying problem! There is no useful information to go on

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to stop using Shared Projects for the 2 projects that were not loading

So if anyone else gets an error like this, you may need to use linked files or another class library instead of shared projects